# How to get the QGraphicsLayoutItem clicked in a QGraphicsWidget with QGraphicsLinearLayout

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qgraphicsitem, qtwidgets

I have QGraphicsLayoutItem placed inside a QGraphicsLinearLayout.
This is added to my QGraphicsWidget.

```
void MyCustomQGraphicsWidget::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent * mouseEvent)
{
    if (mouseEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        qDebug() << "clicked inventory";
    }
}
```

I am having trouble finding a way to get e.g. the index of the item clicked in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do it. But you could calculate and index and use the itemAt() method, suppose the mouse y coordinate is mouseY and item height is H. You can write:

```
int index = mouseY / H; // could be minus some margin
QGraphicsLayoutItem *item = layout.itemAt(index);
```